# Testing local function of angular directive with jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I have a directive defined with local functions, for example :

```
angular.module('clientApp')
  .directive('myDirective', function () {
    return { 
      scope : { user_data : "=myDirective" } , 
      link : function (scope) { 
         function is_valid_float()  { return true; };
         scope.function_on_scope = function ()  { return true; };
      }
    }
  });
```

I'm trying to write a test for `is_valid_float`

```
describe('Directive: myDirective', function () {

  // load the directive's module
  beforeEach(module('clientApp'));

  var element,scope;

  beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope,$compile) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    element = angular.element('<div my-directive></div');
    element = $compile(element)(scope);
    scope.$digest();
  }));

  describe('Test', function () {

    it('Should be defined', function() {
      expect(element).toBeDefined();
      expect(scope.function_on_scope).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('Should check float validity', function () {
      expect(is_valid_float('123')).toBeTrue();
      expect(is_valid_float('123.2.3')).toBeFalse();
    });
  });
});
```

So obviously this is not working. Both the local function `is_valid_float` and the function on the scope. I tried fetching the scope from the element but i'm getting an empty scope.

Testing directives in angular has always been a mystery to me so i'll appreciate some help with this. Thanks.

I'm using jasmine and karma.

Comment: You can't test a private function. You should check the behaviour of the directive as observed from "outside". How that behaviour is implemented is irrelevant.

Comment: Well, This behavior is invoked by pasting data so i don't know how can i reach it from the outside... you happen to know why I cannot get a reference to the correct scope ? eg. the `function_on_scope` in this case ?

Comment: Because your directive declares an isolate scope, so `function_on_scope` **is** defined, but not on the scope you are looking for it :)

Comment: I've also tried fetching the scope from the element via `element.scope()` (as several SO answers suggested), i get a different scope but still not the one i need.

Comment: Because `element.scope()` does not give you the isolate scope. Try `element.isolateScope()`...

Comment: Any solution to this situation???